# NPM CI Cross-Platform Reliability

Tags: node.js, npm-install

Our NodeJS application should run on Linux and Windows servers. We have the following dilemma:

- If we run `npm i` as our CI Build then we sometimes get errors due to differences between the developers laptop's NPM and the build server.
- However, if we run `npm ci` then the build will presumably be locked to the platform of the developers laptop (Windows) and not work on a linux build server.

Maybe our assumptions are incorrect:

- Do we need to build 2 versions of our app: one for each platform?
- Does `npm ci` lock us into the platform of the developer's machine through `package-lock.json`?

Examples of builds working on developers Windows laptops and on Windows servers but not on a Linux server are apps like `strapi` or packages like `sharp` which compile stuff for the platform (.dlls for windows, godknowswhat for linux).

Comment: npm ci installs according to the package-lock.json which should be the same for all developers and ci environment since it’s committed. 

Some npm packages are platform dependent, so you will need separate build artifacts if you deploy to both windows and linux.

Comment: The question is CAN I build 2 different environments with `npm ci`? I was concerned this would lock us into a platform.

Comment: I see. I do not believe `npm ci` is what you're looking for; it is not a platform-agnostic command. I believe Dockerizing your app is one approach that will work for you. Another is multiple builds from your CI; e.g.: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/

Comment: So we're back to the start of my dilemma: if use `npm i` on 2 different build servers (linux and windows) I run the risk of NOT installing according to package-lock.json and thus ending up with different package versions in build as compared to the developer environment.

Comment: Running `npm ci` on the build server risks the node-js bindings to platform builds of the c++ source being different - but the JS packages themselves are not different. I would say this is a relatively minor risk.

Comment: I have compared a Win vs Linux build of a project containing the `sharp` image library which on windows contains .dll files inside the `node_modules` folder. These files are lacking when building on Linux when using `npm i`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no portable way to create a portable node_modules folder, even if all dependencies are pure javascript ones.

I found this the hard way as it seems that npm created different scripts on Windows, like ones ending in `.ps1`, something that does not happen on POSIX platforms.

That means, that no way to track node_modules in git either.